# SignalR client(SignalA) on android, does not work

Tags: android, signalr

I am a beginner android programer. I'm having trouble with [SignalA](https://github.com/erizet/SignalA). Someone tried to run SignalA client? How does it work??? 
I do everything as wrote Erick: Download SignalA.LongPolling. Added a reference to SignalA.LongPolling, added on SignalA.LongPolling  basic-http-client.

Then added to the **MainActivity**:

```
package com.example.testdemo;

import com.zsoft.SignalA.Connection;
import com.zsoft.SignalA.Transport.StateBase;
import com.zsoft.SignalA.transport.longpolling.LongPollingTransport;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        String url = "http://signalrcalc.apphb.com/";
         Connection con = new com.zsoft.SignalA.Connection(url, this, new LongPollingTransport()) {

                @Override
                public void OnError(Exception exception) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "On error: " + exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void OnMessage(String message) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Message: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                @Override
                public void OnStateChanged(StateBase oldState, StateBase newState) {
                }
            };

            con.Start();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And got an errors:

```
04-25 07:05:30.112: E/AndroidRuntime(275): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-25 07:05:30.112: E/AndroidRuntime(275): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.zsoft.SignalA.transport.longpolling.ConnectingState$1
04-25 07:05:30.112: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.zsoft.SignalA.transport.longpolling.ConnectingState.OnRun(ConnectingState.java:39)
04-25 07:05:30.112: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.zsoft.SignalA.transport.longpolling.StopableStateWithCallback.Run(StopableStateWithCallback.java:29)
04-25 07:05:30.112: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.zsoft.SignalA.ConnectionBase.SetNewState(ConnectionBase.java:46)
04-25 07:05:30.112: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.zsoft.SignalA.transport.longpolling.DisconnectedState.OnRun(DisconnectedState.java:42)
04-25 07:05:30.112: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.zsoft.SignalA.Transport.StateBase.Run(StateBase.java:28)
04-25 07:05:30.112: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.zsoft.SignalA.transport.longpolling.DisconnectedState.Start(DisconnectedState.java:25)
04-25 07:05:30.112: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.zsoft.SignalA.ConnectionBase.Start(ConnectionBase.java:127)
04-25 07:05:30.112: E/AndroidRuntime(275):  at com.example.testdemo.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
```

How to run it, I dont know... (((

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your building from the source. When you've cloned the github repo, do the following.

```
git submodule init
and then
git submodule update
```

it will initialize the basic-http-client, that is included in the project as a submodule. Then you dont need to install the jar.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I got this error as well. I managed to get Signala working by including the basic-http-client-android-0.88.jar and the parallel-http-client.jar.

The latter lib is in Signala's master branch, compile it with the other libs and copy it to your project. The former lib you need to download here https://code.google.com/p/basic-http-client/

I'm using android studio instead of eclipse, so I had a few issues with gradle too; if you run into these, be sure to include the following in your build.gradle under dependencies:

```
compile files('libs/signala.jar','libs/basic-http-client-android-0.88.jar','libs/parallel-basic-http-client.jar','libs/signala.longpolling.jar')
```

Comment: I had the exact same problem had the libraries imported BUT at project level. I had to go to Project Structure, select the Project Module, and add the libraries in the Dependencies tab. Only after that, it staterted to work.

Comment: Have a look at the demo projects to see how I've configured my Gradle builds. Or include SignalA from Maven Central.

Answer (score 0):

I have also encountered many issues referencing SignalA in my project. I tried to reference SignalA, SignalA.LongPolling and parallel-basic-http-client into my project. After importing basic-http-client-android-0.88.jar library into SignalA.LongPolling and parallel-basic-http-client as project libraries I was able to compile my project without any errors. However, when I tried to open the Signalr HubConnection, the app gets crashed. The error I got is quite similar to @Kiran's error.

I have spent few hours playing with it and finally managed to make it work without any errors. My method was to export the 'src' folders in the following libraries as Jar Files:
- SignalA
- SignalA.LongPolling
- parallel-basic-http-client

And copied those .jar files + basic-http-client-android-0.88.jar into my project (Workspace/my_app/libs/).

As SignalA is the only solution for SignalR on Android Platform, I thought of sharing a complete workaround with the help seekers here.

You may watch this video to follow instructions step-by-step!

> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f9ih_M7PC10

Comment: Nice video! I just want to mention that I've uploaded SignalA as an aar to Maven Central. Hopefully that makes it easier to use the library. See the readme on github for details.